# Calling controller inside a controller

Tags: symfony

Why it gives the following error when calling controller inside a controller?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   /home/web/project/*symfony2*/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php
>   on line 149

In the controller I called a class that extends `Controller`:

```
class DemoController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $object = new \Acme\DemoBundle\Service\Object();
        $object->method();
    }
    // ...
}
```

The class is something like this:

```
# Acme/DemoBundle/Service/Object.php
class Object extends Controller
{
    public function method()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(); // the problem
        // ...
    }
}
```

When I use `$this` to call service, doctrine, or something else like within a controller, the error occurred. Otherwise, it works.

How can I use, for example, doctrine inside this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$object->setContainer($this->container);
```

before you call `method()`

Edit:
Basically it's a bad idea to have a service extend `Controller` but if you **really** need to do this, try to add this

```
your.service:
  class: Your\Class
  arguments: [...]
  calls:
    - [ setContainer, [@service_container] ]
```

in your service configuration file (probably `service.yml`)

Comment: thanks. it works. Is there any way of this? Especially solving the problem inside the class. Because, I am going to use the class (as a service) in lots of place and it will be repetition.

Comment: You are great. Could you please very shortly tell why it is a bad idea?

Comment: The `Controller` class is designed for routing targets (actions) but you are using it as a service. Why exactly are you doing this? Every function in the `Controller` class is basically a wrapper for different services e.g. `Controller::get()` which is a shortcut to `$this->container->get()`. So by injecting the service container in your service (`arguments: [@service_container]`) you could do the same without extending `Controller`.

Comment: Just to follow up on @prehfeldt's excellent response, what you should be doing is injecting only those services that your service needs to do it's job.  Need an entity manager?  Then inject the entity manager.  Very few services will need access to everything in the container.